# Select WHERE clause, split column value and check

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table schema

```
id   name     type
1    ABC      1,2,3,4
2    PQR      2,3,5 
3    XYZ      1,4
4    TCS      3,1
5    PPP      2,3
```

Here I wants to result display like following i.e, where type is 1 and 4.
Result :-

```
id   name     type
1    ABC      1,2,3,4
3    XYZ      1,4
4    TCS      3,1
```

Comment: Did you try any query,If yes please show

Comment: Can you change the schema? Parsing csv isn't really a good use of sql.

Comment: @Matthew,I also agree with you

Comment: i have try like. "select * from tbl_name where type like '%1,%' or type like '%4,%'"

but at last condition i put "," so it will neglact

Comment: @Matthew i cant able to change schema it contain thousands of records. and i dont have permission to change these schema

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function for that:

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to ***N*** if the string ***str*** is in the string list ***strlist*** consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings **separated by “,” characters**.
>   **Returns 0** if ***str*** is not in ***strlist*** or if ***strlist*** is the empty string.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
     FIND_IN_SET(1, type)
  OR FIND_IN_SET(4, type)
```

Output:

```
╔════╦══════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║  TYPE   ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ ABC  ║ 1,2,3,4 ║
║  3 ║ XYZ  ║ 1,4     ║
║  4 ║ TCS  ║ 3,1     ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/986f16/2)

#### [SQLFiddle with more data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab157/2)

Comment: Also you can use `AND` instead of `OR` in `WHERE` condition if you want both values [in the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab157/3).

Comment: -1 Because normalization is definitely the preferred way to go.

Comment: @Strawberry - When we have predefined function then why don't we use it?

Comment: Because normalization (to at least 3NF) is fundamental to schema design. Yes, there's a place for this function, and yes it is blisteringly fast, but this user is clearly a newbie - we should be teaching them the proper way first, and the hacks only as a last resort.

Comment: +1 @Strawberry the OP said he cannot alter schema. This seems like **the** solution on the mySql platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check all conditions like,

```
select * from table where
type like '1' OR type like '4' 
OR type like '1,%' OR type like '4,%' 
OR type like '%,1' OR type like '%,4' 
OR type like '%,1,%' OR type like '%,4,%'
```

Comment: It will check all conditions

Comment: or in a single check, `',' + type + ',' like '%,4,%'`

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM user_master WHERE TYPE LIKE '%4%' OR  TYPE LIKE '%1%'

Comment: @shin - This pattern is not asked in the question

Comment: This won't even produce the example result in the question.